# TypeError: array(['cycling'], dtype=object) is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, machine-learning

hi I've made an text classification classifier which i've used in this it is returning me an array and I want to return jsonresponse but the last line of code giving me error 'array(['cycling'], dtype=object) is not JSON serializable'

```
def classify_text(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get('text'):
        test = []
        text = request.POST.get('text')
        text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', text)
        text = text.lower()
        text = text.split()
        ps = PorterStemmer()
        text = [ps.stem(word) for word in text if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
        text = ' '.join(text)
        test.append(text)

        pred = cv.transform(test).toarray()
        pred = svm_model_linear.predict(pred)
        return JsonResponse(pred, safe=False)
```

Comment: instead of devote please provide me answer

Comment: What is the type of `pred` ?

Comment: it holds the prediction of the classifier which is "'pred=  ['cycling']"

Comment: Is it a numpy array object ?

Comment: I think that method `svn_model_linear.predict` returns a numpy array object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `numpy array` to a `list` object, which can be easily done using [.tolist()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method on the numpy array object.

**Example**:

```
pred_list = pred.tolist()
return JsonResponse(pred_list, safe=False)
```